# Pass NULL from a VB6 window to a .NET nullable Int32

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, int, nullable

I have a VB6 window that calls a .NET method, passing inputs from its control's values to the C# code.

I'd like to be able to pass `NULL` to the C# parameter of (`Int32?`), but I haven't found anything in my VB6 code that allows me to do so.

Is this possible? If so, what value do I need to pass from VB6 to get `NULL` in my .NET method?

Comment: `Variant`s can be null in VB6 if I recall correctly. How to marshal it across to .NET I am not sure.. since its not a "pure null" (if there is such a thing) as far as I remember.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, but if the C# parameter is a nullable int, can I pass Nothing or Empty as well?

Comment: Not sure.. it would be quick to test the theory though...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yup, I've tried Nothing, Empty, vbNull (it's a value here, not sure if VB6 has it in general). No luck so far, an exception just gets thrown

Comment: Your other option is to allocate an invalid value to it.. say, `-1` if the business rule suits that. Then you can check it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead that was my original approach, but the review points disallowed hardcoded values. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  In fact, you can't even *see* the method in your VB6 project.  Running Tlbexp.exe on your .NET assembly should always produce a warning that looks similar to this:

> TlbExp : warning TX8013117D : Type library exporter warning processing 'IFoo.test(arg), ClassLibrary1'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.

Which was produced by:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IFoo {
    void test(int? arg);
}
```

The resulting type library will *not* have the test() method.  It can't be called.  The generic type it is complaining about is `Nullable<T>`, your Int32? is short-hand notation for that.

Long story short, your C# is simply not suitable to be used from a COM client like VB6.  You must change the declaration of your argument to *object*.  Test for null first, then cast to (short), the natural fit for VB6.  Or use Convert.ToInt32() to be flexible about the value type that the client uses.

Comment: That's exactly the error I was getting! I figured (and feared) as much, thanks very much anyways :)

Comment: It is quite essential that you **always** mention an error message you see.  Saves everybody a lot of time, Google really likes it too.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass Nothing to the parameter. It acts as null value.

Comment: no luck, it generates a Compiler error when I use Nothing as an input parameter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has been changed for the years passed since @HansPassant answer but I was able to use C# nullables in VB6 easily:

C#

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(...)]
public class Foo
{
    private int? _arg;

    public int? Arg => _arg;

    public void Test(int? arg)
    {
        _arg = arg;
    }
}
```

VB6:

```
Dim foo As New Foo
foo.Test CLng(1234)
Debug.Print foo.Arg '1234
foo.Test Empty
Debug.Print IsEmpty(foo.Arg) 'True
foo.Test CLng(4321)
Debug.Print foo.Arg '4321
```